# Duplicate entry key for key primary

Tags: mysql, database

I have encountered some error on my codes. It says

Error code 1062, SQL state 23000: Duplicate entry '88889' for key 'PRIMARY'
Line 15, column 1

Error code 1062, SQL state 23000: Duplicate entry '87990' for key 'PRIMARY'
Line 20, column 1

Error code 1062, SQL state 23000: Duplicate entry '79678' for key 'PRIMARY'
Line 25, column 1

Error code 1062, SQL state 23000: Duplicate entry '88799' for key 'PRIMARY'
Line 30, column 1

Error code 1062, SQL state 23000: Duplicate entry '78998' for key 'PRIMARY'
Line 35, column 1

And here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studentrecord (
student_id VARCHAR(7),
stud_first_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
stud_last_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
stud_date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
stud_address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
stud_program VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
stud_marital_status INT(2) NOT NULL,
stud_country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
) ENGINE=innodb;

-- insert a sample data
INSERT INTO studentrecord VALUES(
'88889','Albukori','Zaman Khan','1969-07-08',
'4-5, Dead Wood Street 5, 12000 Sintok, Kedah','MSc. IT',
'1','Malaysia');

INSERT INTO studentrecord VALUES(
'87990','Haslina','Mahathir','1970-11-12',
'345, New Smart Village, 17100 Nilai, N. Sembilan','MSc. ICT',
'2','Malaysia');

INSERT INTO studentrecord VALUES(
'79678','Mohammed','Fajr','1975-04-20',
'Pearl Apt, Level 10, Al-Hijr, 45200 Abu Dhabi','MSc. Expert System',
'2','UEA');

INSERT INTO studentrecord VALUES(
'88799','Mustar','Mohd Dali','1979-06-24',
'345, Side Village, Kerian, 12300 Jawa Barat','MSc. MultiMedia',
'1','Indonesia');

INSERT INTO studentrecord VALUES(
'78998','Satkorn','Chengmo','1968-01-26',
'34 Uptown Street #4, Tech Park, 78100 Bangkok','MSc. IT',
'2','Thailand');
```

Thanks for your response. I hope you would help me, im very new to this

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` **`IF NOT EXISTS`**--this answers your question. To solve your issue, drop the table, then create.

Comment: Your table definition has no attribute student_id change primary key to id

Comment: I am actually creating database on java

Answer (score 1):

That code can only be run once, the system is trying to enter the same records twice and so is failing. it sounds like the table studentrecord has a primary key which is the first value you are trying to enter e.g.78998

To get around this you can make your code reentrant by changing it to something like this (please bear in mind this is for t-sql not mysql)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studentrecord  WHERE id = 1878998)
INSERT INTO studentrecord VALUES( '78998','Satkorn','Chengmo','1968-01-26', '34 Uptown Street #4, Tech Park, 78100 Bangkok','MSc. IT', '2','Thailand');
```

EDIT: as Sasha Salauyou says, you can also drop the table first

Comment: Thank you Sasha Salauyou and martpendle. It run now. I just drop table and create again